# r - data.table coercion error when updating a column by group

Tags: r, data.table

This question is best explained with an example

Consider this data

```
library(data.table)
dt1 <- data.table(id = rep(1L:3L, each = 3),
                  val = rep(1L:3L, times = 3))

## The 'val' column is an integer
str(dt1)

# Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':    9 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ id : int  1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3
# $ val: int  1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3
# - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

If we divide the `val` column by the max of the `val` column, it coerces it to numeric - no problems

```
dt1[, val := val / max(val)][]
#     id       val
# 1:  1 0.3333333
# 2:  1 0.6666667
# ...

str(dt1)
# Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':    9 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ id : int  1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3
# $ val: num  0.333 0.667 1 0.333 0.667 ...
# - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

Loading the same data again, and this time performing the same calculation by a **group** causes a 'coercion' error

```
dt1 <- data.table(id = rep(1L:3L, each = 3),
                  val = rep(1L:3L, times = 3))

dt1[, val := val / max(val), by = id][]
# Error in `[.data.table`(dt1, , `:=`(val, val/max(val)), by = id) : 
#   Type of RHS ('double') must match LHS ('integer'). To check and coerce would 
#   impact performance too much for the fastest cases. Either change the type of 
#   the target column, or coerce the RHS of := yourself (e.g. by using 1L instead of 1)
```

I'm aware the solution to this is to [convert the class of the column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29643838/5977215) before updating the column

```
dt1[, val := as.double(val)][, val := val / max(val), by = id][]
```

However, why is the update permitted when not using a group, but throws an error when the group is included?

Comment: AFAIU when you are not using groups, your expression is evaluated for whole column and column replaced, then there is no conflict of types. When you do grouping, expression is evaluated for group, put into origin column, which is still of different type until all groups are processed. So there is a conflict and the whole column is converted.

Comment: In the doc `?\`:=\``: "It is best to get the column types correct up front and stick to them. Changing a column type is possible but deliberately harder: provide a whole column as the RHS."