# How to Change Type of Target Column for a Rolling Mean Function

Tags: r, data.table, zoo

I am trying to calculate the rolling mean (last 20 Periods) of stock returns by a certain ID (called PERMNO). Firstly, I just tried to create the rolling mean. I worked on it with this code:

```
CRSP_dt[, rolltest1 := rollmeanr(Return, 20, na.rm = TRUE, fill = NA)]
```

which did not work. However, when I try it with this code:

```
CRSP_dt[, rolltest2 := rollapplyr(Return, 20, mean, na.rm = TRUE, fill = NA)]
```

it actually works, so I am not entirely sure, why?

Secondly, I tried to calculate the rolling mean by PERMNO, so I added the "by" addition:

```
CRSP_dt[, rolltest2 := rollapplyr(Return, 10, mean, na.rm = TRUE, fill = NA),
    by = PERMNO]
```

Now, it returns an error "Error in `[.data.table`(CRSP_dt, , `:=`(rolltest2, rollapplyr(Return,  : 
  Type of RHS ('logical') must match LHS ('double'). To check and coerce would impact performance too much for the fastest cases. Either change the type of the target column, or coerce the RHS of := yourself (e.g. by using 1L instead of 1)". 
Since then I have been trying to convert the target column into a "Double" too, by using the solution from [this overstack solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29643820/how-to-change-type-of-target-column-when-doing-by-group-in-a-data-table-in-r), resulting in:

```
CRSP_dt[, rolltest2:= as.numeric(rolltest2)][, rolltest2 := rollapplyr(Return, 10, mean, na.rm = TRUE, fill = NA),
    by = PERMNO]
```

Unfortunately, it still gives out the same error code, so I am not sure, how to proceed from here.

Comment: I added the relevant packages to your tags, please check if they are correct.

Comment: Yeah, those are the packages, thanks. I did not know that I had to add them.

Comment: At least somewhere in your question, yeah. `library` calls are also appreciated. Remember there are thousands of packages.

Comment: Also, you first attempt does not work as `na.rm` is not an accepted argument. See `?rollmean`: _"The default methods of rollmean and rollsum do not handle inputs that contain NAs."_

Comment: Hi @Axeman, thanks for the clarification and help. But even when I leave out the `na.rm` and run `CRSP_dt[, rolltest1 := rollmeanr(Return, 10, fill = NA)]`, it just returns me a column full of NAs like before.

Comment: Yes, it can't handle inputs with NA's. So it returns NA. As documented.

Comment: Sorry, I just wanted to write this, I didn't get it fully. So I cannot use rollmean at all, only rollapply, good to know! Thanks!

Comment: And do you know how to solve the error with the "logical" value type?

Comment: I tried using:
`CRSP_dt %>% group_by(CRSP_dt$PERMNO) %>%
  mutate(rolltest2 = rollapplyr(Return, 10, mean, na.rm = TRUE, fill = NA))`

But unfortunately, it did not work. It does not differentiate between my different PERMNO-IDs, but rather continues calculating the rolling mean.

Comment: You can convert the rowtest2 column to numeric first