# How do you change the type of target column when using .() group by in R data.table

Tags: r, data.table

This question is similar to [How to change type of target column when doing := by group in a data.table in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29643820/how-to-change-type-of-target-column-when-doing-by-group-in-a-data-table-in-r) however, I need to use `.()` notation.

Example:

```
a <- data.table(ID = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C"), 
                TYPE = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3), 
                CLASS = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6))

b <- a[, .(Count = .N, "Failure Count" = sum(CLASS == "2"), 
       "Median DIF" = median(TYPE)), by = ID]
```

Is there a way to do this using this different notation? The reason for this is I want to create a new table versus adding a column to the existing table using the `:=` notation.

Comment: Your title says *"change the type of target column"* but your details say *"avoid taking a copy" (i.e. take a reference?)* . Those are two different things - which is it?

Comment: My reference to "change the type of target column" is in `b`, the error was that it was expecting a double and got an integer because `a$TYPE` is an integer. And the second part "avoid taking a copy" is in reference to I don't want `b` to contain all of the same columns as `a`, only the columns I specified.

Comment: The title is still very confusing and mistaken. The whole point of data.table `:=`  is it operates in-place i.e. no copying. But when you create a summary/aggregation using `=`, you want to create a new table. Moreover `a[..., TYPE := median(TYPE),... ]` would clobber the existing data, which is presumably wrong.; and in this case it would try to store a numeric in an integer. You're not asking about taking a reference vs making a copy, you're really asking "only keep selected columns in the summary". And that's handled by listing only the columns you want to keep in the `.(...)` j-expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently all you have to do is add `as.numeric()` inside of `median()`.

```
b <- a[, .(Count = .N, "Failure Count" = sum(CLASS == "2"), 
      "Median DIF" = median(as.numeric(TYPE))), by = ID]
```